# spark job (scala) write type Date to Cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I'm using DSE 5.1 (spark 2.0.2.6 and cassandra 3.10.0.1652)

My Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE ks.tbl (
   dk int,
   date date,
   ck int,
   val int,
PRIMARY KEY (dk, date, ck)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date DESC, ck ASC);
```

with the following data:

```
 dk | date       | ck | val
----+------------+----+-----
  1 | 2017-01-01 |  1 | 100
  1 | 2017-01-01 |  2 | 200
```

My code must read this data and write the same thing but with yesterday's date (it compiles successfully):

```
package com.datastax.spark.example

import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import com.github.nscala_time.time._
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._

object test extends App {

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DSE calculus app TEST")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val yesterday= (DateTime.now - 1.days).toString(StaticDateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))

  val tbl = sc.cassandraTable("ks","tbl").select("dk","date","ck","val").where("dk=1")

  tbl.map(row => (row.getInt("dk"),yesterday,row.getInt("ck"),row.getInt("val"))).saveToCassandra("ks","tbl")

  sc.stop()
  sys.exit(0)
}
```

When I run this app:

```
dse spark-submit --class com.datastax.spark.example.test test-assembly-0.1.jar
```

It fails to properly write to Cassandra. It seems the date variable is not inserted in the map correctly.
The error I get is:

```
Error:
WARN  2017-05-08 22:23:16,472 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, <IP of one of my nodes>): java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to ks.tbl.
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:207)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:175)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:112)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:145)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.writeInternal(TableWriter.scala:175)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.insert(TableWriter.scala:162)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:149)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

However, when I insert a date (string) directly in the map statement as follows, the code does insert the data correctly:

```
tbl.map(row => (row.getInt("dk"),"2017-02-02",row.getInt("ck"),row.getInt("val"))).saveToCassandra("ks","tbl")
```

It also insert the data correctly if I set yesterday to an integer (days since epoch). This will be optimal, but can't get 'yesterday' to behave this way

EDIT: This does not insert data correctly, actually. No matter if I set 'yesterday' to 1 or 100,000,000 it always insert epoch ('1970-01-01)

The code that fails behave correctly and as I would expect in the DSE Spark console.

I just can't figure out how what I'm doing wrong. Any help is welcome.

EDIT2: The [excecutor 0 stderr log](https://pastebin.com/6E7q7Twm) does show that its trying to insert a Null value in the column date, that's obviously not possible since its a clustering column.

Comment: You need to post the executor logs. Because the driver only sees the "failed to write statements" it doesn't get the individual tries and failures that caused it.

Comment: Do you mean the stdout stderr from all executors on the application in the spark master UI?

Comment: At least the one you got the exception from :)

Comment: @RussS Thank you a ton! With that I realized its trying to insert a Null value. I just edited my question with a pastebin link to the log. Still i have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: I bet it's because the "String" you are generating doesn't parse correctly in your insert ... (maybe)

Comment: Or possibly a serialization error? The closure for "yesterday" doesn't move correctly?

Comment: I know i'm leaving a lot of comments here, but what happens if you make that into a "lazy val" instead ...

Comment: I do appreciate your comments, there's not too many of them, each one moves us closer to the answer. I'm now out of the office and the cluster can only be accessed locally. Tomorrow morning I'll try the lazy eval and post the results. Also will do other scenarios with different data types and tables, just to check if its a parsing issue or a java to scala issue. Thank you for your help so far Russ

Comment: @RussS your suggestion to change yesterday definition to a lazy val worked. I don't understand why tho. I'll keep doing some more testing before posting an answer.

Comment: I'll explain in the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing code for a Spark Job it's important to realize when particular variables are set and when they are serialized. Let's take a look at a note from the `App` trait docs

> Caveats
>
> It should be noted that this trait is implemented using the
>   DelayedInit functionality, which means that fields of the object will
>   not have been initialized before the main method has been executed.

This means references to the variables used in the body of the `App` are possibly not initialized on the Executors when the code is actually being run.

My guess is that the lambda you have written contains a reference to a val which is initialized in the Delayed init portion of the App class. This means the serialized version of the code on the executor which doesn't run the `Main` method gets the uninitialized version of the value (null).

Switching the constant to a `lazy val` (or moving it into a separate object or class) would fix this issue by making sure the value is initialized remotely (lazy val) or simply serialized initialized (separate class/object).

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what is your problem. 
You may see full log file. You just attach a part of them... 
Today have similar error, when create keyspace with replication_factor: 3 when I had only one cassandra instance.

So i change it and problem is gone.

```
ALTER KEYSPACE "some_keyspace_name" WITH REPLICATION =
  { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
```

[Here is my error.log file](https://gist.github.com/Qwedir/e39255bf5606dbc4daf81b852fc38f20)

And important part of log:

```
Logging.scala[logError]:72) - Failed to execute: com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RichBoundStatement@4746499f
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replicas available for query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 required but only 1 alive)
```